# How to solve the problem of object cannot be converted to closure in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wan t to validate a field where a employee can apply for a holiday which categories by leave category. and in leave category i specify the date and when an employee request for leave from that category then he cannot exceed the total days which is specify in leave category day, I tried so far this

```
$startdate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
        $enddate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);;
        $diff = $startdate->diffInDays($enddate);
        $days=LeaveCategory::where('id',$request->category)->first();  
  'category' =>[
                'required',
                function($days,$diff,$fail){
                if($days->days < $diff){
                    return $fail("You cant");
            }
    }],
```

but it gives me a error called Object of class Closure could not be converted to string. Please help me to solve that

Comment: Please show the value of `$request->start_date` using `dd($request->start_date);`

Comment: my calculation is quite ok, if i dd($diff) then i will get 10 days and if i dd($days->days) then i will get 5 days. Btw if i dd start date and end date then i will get the dates that i am requesting

Comment: @TanvirAhmed The problem is when you have passed function inside validation.

Comment: i need to validate this inside validation then what should i do

Comment: im assuming the array syntax is from some array you are making that you aren't showing?  and what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: if you are using Laravel < 5.6 I don't believe you will have the option to use a Closure for a custom rule

Comment: The code you have shown is invalid.  Please edit your question and fix it so we can try to help.